# how to return two decimal places string type

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, return

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Loan
{
    double loan;
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Loan: " + loan;
    }
}
class Frame
{
    String framename;
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Frame: " + framename;
    }
}
class Circle
{
    double radius;
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Circle: " + radius;
    }
}
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Loan loan = new Loan();
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        Circle circle = new Circle();

        loan.loan = input.nextDouble();
        frame.framename = input.next();
        circle.radius = input.nextDouble();

        ArrayList<Object> mylist = new ArrayList<Object>();
        mylist.add(loan);
        mylist.add(frame);
        mylist.add(circle);

        System.out.println(mylist.get(0));
        System.out.println(mylist.get(1));
        System.out.println(mylist.get(2));

    }
}
```

> I want to make the loan and the circle return two decimal places using the toString method how can i achieve that.... the objects should be in an Arraylist of objects.I tried using System.out.printf("%.2f",mylist.get(2)) but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the double type fields to String so that the return type is correct and in the process of converting you specify the which format of the string you want in this case specify 2 decimal places.

```
class Loan
{
    double loan;
    public String toString()
    {
        String loanstring = String.format ("%.2f", loan);
        return "Loan: " + loanstring;
    }
}
class Circle
{
    double radius;
    public String toString()
    {
        String radiusstring = String.format ("%.2f", radius);
        return "Circle: " + radiusstring;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare your list as `ArrayList<Loan> mylist = new ArrayList<Loan>();`  instead of `ArrayList<Object> mylist = new ArrayList<Object>();` then you can get the expected result by doing:

```
 System.out.printf("%.2f",mylist.get(0).loan);
```

As an aside, ideally, all fields of a class should be private and create getters and setters where necessary. So, in this case, you can make `loan` private in the `Loan` class and then create a getter for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a ArrayList of type "Object". So you can put everthing into these list.

Set the type of the ArrayList to "Loan"

```
ArrayList<Loan> mylist = new ArrayList<Loan>();
```

Than you can get the loanvalue from listitems.

```
printf("%.2f",mylist.get(0).loan);
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i see mylist.get(0) is an object of type Loan and not a double, thats probably why it doesn‘t work, because the printf approach is the right approach to this.

you should also make your ArrayList an ArrayList instead, it‘s cleaner and might have helped you to avoid confusing the type from the begining.